# C equation returns different value than my calculated value

Tags: c

I have this equation in solving the temperature from a temperature sensor.

variables are:

```
unsigned char AD_DATA; values is usually 100- 110;
int TEMP;
```

the original equation:

```
TEMP = 50 - (AD_DATA * 175) / 1000;
```

I changed that to:

```
TEMP = 500 - (AD_DATA * 1750) / 1000;
```

the reason for this is because TEMP is an integer, and thus on the first equation when it is calculated that there is a decimal it will be automatically rounded, so i changed it so that decimal will be included in the number.

The reason why I am not using float is because in the MCU I am using, whenever I declare a float variable inside the ISR(interrupt service routine) it will return an error thus I needed to be creative in using only INT, double will also return an error.

> Now using an AD_DATA value of 100

the 1st equation will result to: **32.5**, but since its an int it is now 33.

the 2nd equation should output 325, but in my output is **521**

I need to include the decimal in my display thus it is really important for it to be included in the equation.

My ISR routine:

```
__interrupt void ADC_int(void){
IO_ADCSH.bit.INT = 0;
AD_DATA = IO_ADCRLH.DATA8;
TEMP = 500 - (AD_DATA * 1750) / 1000;
}
```

MCU specs

```
int 2bytes
long 4bytes
unsigned char 1byte
```

Comment: what are the mcu specs, especially, register bit length

Comment: The maximum value for an `unsigned int` is 65535, but `100 * 1750` is 175000, so you have an overflow.

Comment: Use `1750L` - make it `long`

Comment: Even better: you have undefined behaviour. Use a bigger integer-like for AD_DATA and your problems are solved.

Comment: Yep, running on a processor with 4-byte ints, I do get 325.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a quick hack, you can replace `(AD_DATA * 1750) / 1000` by `(AD_DATA * 7) / 4`.

For more ideas, read below.

---

Note that by changing

```
TEMP = 50 - (AD_DATA * 175) / 1000;
```

to

```
TEMP = 500 - (AD_DATA * 1750) / 1000;
```

you changed the meaning of the `TEMP` variable. Assuming it means "temperature" (doesn't really matter), it meant "temperature in degrees", and now it means "temperature in units of 1/10 degree". However, why did you multiply by 10? Just for convenience, I guess - you are not obliged to use powers of 10 for your units. You can use any other number, provided you remember what it was, and treat the result `TEMP` accordingly (e.g. divide it by 10 when printing it out). So the best number to use is 40: it eliminates a division (or rather, postpones it to later lines of code) and so avoids a loss of precision.

```
TEMP_MULTIPLIED_BY_40 = 2000 - AD_DATA * 7;
```

Comment: that moment when you forget your fractions, thank you for this clean solution. I should have known better :)

Answer (score 3):

My first guess according to the information you gave,
is that the register length is 16bits causing the operand to overflow when you multiply AD_DATA by 1000.

the largest value a int could hold is 32762 (from the top of my head , more like 0x7FFF), even unsigned it is insufficient to hold AD_DATA*1000 ( wich in you case would be 18*1000=18000 ), the value will be truncated to 16bits, giving a negative number in the process.

you can fix that by specifying the length of your operator in your expression and casting AD_DATA to a 32bit word.

Comment: i did get some negative numbers, i tried using long but it still returns 519 instead of 325, and i still cant use double or float inside the interrupt routine

Comment: store AD_DATA in a long first or cast it to a long in the expression

Comment: @magicianIam No need to store/cast `AD_DATA` as `long`.  Just multiply by a `long` constant.

Comment: @chux what do you mean by multiply it to a long constant?

Comment: @magicianIam `TEMP = 500 - (AD_DATA * 1750L) / 1000;`  (note 'L')

Comment: @chux it wont work, returns an error, just like when i try to use double or float

Comment: @magicianIam The info about "an error" is important; you should paste the error message into your question.

Comment: there is no error when compiling, it is when running it in the MCU that causes an interrupt priority error, it does not specify it and simply closes, thus i cannot really tell what is the error.

Comment: did you try storing AD_DATA in a long ?

Comment: @magicianIam Given the limitations, maybe confine scaling to 16-bit.  With 16-bit `unsigned` and values 100-110 --> `TEMP = 500 - (AD_DATA * 175*5u) / (100*5u);` or since `AD_DATA` is only 1 of 11 values and use a look-up table.  Note; My apologies for so much discussion under another's answer.

Comment: @chux I will give that a try, we are discouraged from calling a function inside an ISR, it would be a little bit better though, but lets try this equations first

Comment: @dvhh yes i did, but it returned the same error i received with the float and double, could be because the size for an ISR is limited

Comment: then your MCU could not handle 32bits values, you have to get around this limitation. Either by implementing the 32bits logic around 16bits arithmetic, or limit your expression to 16 bits values